# Does Acrobat Pro XI support Retina display?

Tags: display, pdf

I have not been able to find any official word from Adobe on this. A Google search only turns up comments from disgruntled users (such as myself) who complain about lack of support in Acrobat X.

So: does Acrobat Pro XI support Retina display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just installed it: Nope, no retina support yet.

Answer (score 0):

No support for retina with Acrobat Pro XI as of December 2014. Sad because Adobe Illustrator CC displays documents silky smooth. I was under the impression Adobe used the same display engine on both apps)